# Get OneDrive items in default sort order

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

How can I get folder's items in original sort order? I want to get items in the same order as OneDrive folder has online. I have many folders with custom sort arrangements, but I’m always getting items sorted by name only.

```
var res = Client
  .Drive
  .Items[FolderId]
  .Request()
  .Expand("children($expand=thumbnails)")
  .GetAsync(); // where FolderId is variable
```

`res.Children` always contains items sorted by Name only, no matter what `res.Folder.View.SortBy` value is.

I'm using Microsoft Graph Client Library.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use OneDrive or OneDrive for Business?

In OneDrive for Business, Graph only supports sorting by [`name` or `url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/release-notes?view=odsp-graph-online#sorting). For personal OneDrive, only [`name`, `size`, and `lastModifiedDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/optional-query-parameters?view=odsp-graph-online#sorting-collections).

What parameter do you use for sorting when you access your OneDrive with a browser? Is it sorted by date? If so, I'd suggest to add your vote on the [Office User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35016886-add-support-for-descending-sort-order-to-onedrive)

Comment: Question is about OneDrive (personal). I have some folders sorted by Name, some by Date taken and some Custom (Rearrange -> Save sort order)

Comment: Simon's answer is correct. The only properties that are supported for sorting are `name`, `size`, and `lastModifiedDateTime`. I've edited Simon's answer to provide some links to the official documentation for additional details.

Comment: I don't want to sort results. I want to get items in the same order as it was specified for a folder. How is OneDrive website knows how to display items correctly for this folder?

https://onedrive.live.com/?id=74359A6E9F2A325A%21138&cid=74359A6E9F2A325A

I set sort order as Custom and OneDrive website able to display it correctly. Is OneDrive.com & app using Graph API also?